# how to sort an array of strings and integers to show sorted integers first in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array containing integer values and string type characters as such `_`

Here is my array `array = ["_", 2, 3, "_"]` how can I sort them such that it returns like the following: `[2, 3, "_", "_"]` I have tried to sort it with the ruby `.sort()` method but it appears as if `sort()` does not compare integers with strings and therfore returns an error.

is there a ruby method I am not aware of? Any help or guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: hey, yeah sorry my bad. I edited it and fixed it!. Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: `array.map{|e| e.to_s}.sort`

Comment: Your result isn't very specific. How do you want the numbers and the strings to be sorted? Ascending maybe? And what about numeric strings? Or should they simply preserve their relative order? For example, what's the expected result for `['b', 2, '0', 'a', 1]`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you can't compare a string to an integer:

```
> 2<"2"
(irb):15:in `<': comparison of Integer with String failed (ArgumentError)
```

The fix (with your specific example) is to make `array` act as if it is all strings.

Given:

```
array = ["_", 2, 3, "_"]
```

If you just want the result to be a uniform string array:

```
> array.map{|e| e.to_s}.sort
=> ["2", "3", "_", "_"]
```

If you want the elements to maintain their type:

```
> array.map{|e| [e.to_s, e]}.sort.map{|e| e[1]}
=> [2, 3, "_", "_"]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
> array.sort_by{|e| e.to_s}
=> [2, 3, "_", "_"]
```

The *potential* issue here is that if you rely solely on a conversion to a string (which solved the example you gave) you will get a bad result with integers:

```
> array = ["10", 12, 3, "0", "b", "a"]
=> ["10", 12, 3, "0", "b", "a"]
> array.sort_by{|e| e.to_s}
=> ["0", "10", 12, 3, "a", "b"]   # desirable?
```

Which is not entirely solvable by using `.to_i`:

```
> array.sort_by{|e| e.to_i}
=> ["0", "b", "a", 3, "10", 12]   # fixed?
```

Which maybe is best solved by sorting on both:

```
> array.sort_by{|e| [e.to_i, e.to_s]}
=> ["0", "a", "b", 3, "10", 12]
```

Luckily Ruby makes it super easy to choose.

---

Note, `.sort_by` or the other [enumerable sorts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) are *not* a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) so elements that compare equal are potentially returned in different order than given:

```
> array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> array.sort_by{|e| 0}  # make them all compare equal 
=> [9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

To fix *that* now, add an index:

```
> array.each_with_index.sort_by{|e,i| [0,i]}.map(&:first)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or, as pointed out in comments:

```
> array.sort_by.with_index { |e, i| [0, i] }
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I was just about to comment on the order of your last statement but you fixed it (Bravo). that being said you could improve efficiency, and readability IMO, a bit by changing this to `array.sort_by.with_index { |e, i| [0, i] } #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`